# Why is the background of an html tag with the same color different in mobile and laptop?

Tags: html, css, colors, html5-img, web-safe-colors

I made a header area in a web page and set its background color to `#ffc755`.

**Problem:**
When I opened this page on mobile, I noticed that the color is a little bolder.

As an experiment, I tried taking a screenshot from the mobile device and transferred that image file back to my laptop where I saw that **the color was correct**.

What is the reason for this and how can I fix it?

This is the picture I took on my mobile phone. 
**Color may vary depending on your monitor**. You can check it on a laptop and on a mobile:

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3UlH.png)

[image]

Comment: *(Color may vary depending on your monitor)* – isn't this the answer to your question?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've answered your own question already by yourself:

> *"Color may vary depending on your monitor"*.

So I think it depends on the monitor you are looking at. 
Monitors could display more/less colors, are brighter/darker, show different contrast and so on.

If you ran a mobile emulator on you desktop, then the color should not differ on mobile or on your desktop because both are displayed on the same monitor.